# Does CLR still loads the assembly in the process even when it has Ngen'd copy of that assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I was reading an article from Jeffrey Richter' book *CLR via C#*. And I found a nice paragraph about the `NGen.exe` tool.

> Many people believe that it might be possible to ship NGen’d files
>   without shipping the files containing the original IL code, thereby
>   keeping their intellectual property a secret. Unfortunately, this is
>   not possible. At run time, the CLR requires access to the assembly’s
>   metadata (for functions such as reflection and serialization); this
>   requires that the assemblies that contain IL and metadata be shipped.

I just wanted to clear few thing.

1. Does CLR always loads the assembly when the referencing types are there in the assembly.
2. Does it do verification check on it?
3. When it comes to compiling the code (JIT compiler), does it look for NGen'd code and load the compiled native CPU instructions from that file, or doesn't load the assembly at all when NGen'd file is already there?

Answer (score 2):

> Does CLR always loads the assembly when the referencing types are
>   there in the assembly.

No. The CLR will load the assembly once a method is to be JITTED, and is depended an assembly in order to execute. The JIT will instruct the runtime to load that DLL.

> Does it do verification check on it?

Yes, the binder, which is responsible for loading the dll will verify it as a valid assembly via it's metadata in the CLR header (see section below).

> When it comes to compiling the code (JIT compiler), does it look for
>   NGen'd code and load the compiled native CPU instructions from that
>   file, or doesn't load the assembly at all when NGen'd file is already
>   there?

Not sure what you mean by *"NGENED file already there"*, but the native binder will look for the native dll as part of the loading process. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2013/12/11/net-loading-native-ngen-images-and-its-interaction-with-the-gac.aspx) explains the details of loading the assembly to details:

> 1. First the standard fusion binder will kick in to find that assembly.
>      It can find it either in:
>
>    - GAC, which means it is strongly named. The way files are placed in GAC ensures that the binder can extract all the required
>        information about the assembly without physically opening the file
>    - Find it the APPBASE (E.g. the local folder of program.exe). It will proceed to open the IL file and read the assemblies metadata.
> 2. Native binding will proceed only in the default context (more about
>      this in a later post)
> 3. The NativeBinder finds the NI file from the NIC. It reads in the NI
>      file details and metadata
> 4. Verifies the NI is indeed for that very same IL assembly. For that
>      it goes through a rigorous matching process which includes (but not
>      limited to) full assembly name match (same name, version,  public
>      key tokens, culture), time stamp matching (NI has to be newer than
>      IL), MVID (see below)
> 5. Also verifies that the NI has been generated for the same CLR under
>      which it is going to be run (exact .NET version, processor type,
>      etc…) .
> 6. Also ensures that the NI’s dependencies are also valid. E.g. when
>      the NI was generated it bound against a particular version of
>      mscorlib. If that mscorlib native image is not valid then this NI
>      image is also rejected

*Default context*:

> Default context: This is the context where assembly loaded through implicit assembly references or Assembly.Load(…) call lands

Comment: Nicely explained, however few points, will it get the system path / environment variable in the picture at any point time to probe a binary. Also when does it know that there's a native image cache available, and it has to load the same, instead of JIT compilation

Comment: @Mrinal 1. No it won't. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3(v=vs.100).aspx) for the exact probing execution flow. 2. When the metadata in the IL header specifies so.

Comment: I have some clarity but still little confused.

Comment: What I am still confused about is this.

Comment: suppose I have Main function(ofcourse we have one) in my program. and lets say that I am using a type named SomeType in my main function. I have SomeType defined in a library named SomeLibrary.dll. Now i have run NGen.exe on SomeLibrary.dll to get the native Image in some folder location where NGen.exe puts it. so now i have 1 Somelibrary.dll and the native image(native CPU instruction) created by NGen.exe. Now when I run my program containing Main Function. Windows create a process and initializes CLR and loads the exe containing main function. when the CLR scans all the reference Types

Comment: inside my .exe,it finds SomeType type defined inside it. it then creates a internal data structure for this type which holds an entry for functions defined inside the SomeType type. it has created native CPU instruction of my .exe program file. Now when CLR executes it, CLR encounters a SomeType.And now for verification(that function(if any) defined inside SomeType are called correctly) it needs to load the dll. And  then it can sends JIT to verify it and compile it. or is it that it doesnt need to verify at all and directly load the Native image that was created for SomeLibrary.dll into

Comment: the process where the CLR is hosted and my .exe is also there.

Comment: This is what i really wanted to clear up. Because even when the CLR is converting my application containing Main function. it needs to validate that if i have referenced SomeType in my Main and if i am calling that fucntion(in SomeType) correctly or not

Comment: Please consider the above 4 comments as 1 question.

Comment: Thank you mate. your previous post was helpful.

Comment: *or is it that it doesnt need to verify at all and directly load the Native image that was created for SomeLibrary.dll* It still needs to verify the dll. The native binder will load the native image, which still includes metadata.

Comment: I think I get it now. Native image and my original .dll both have metadata. And when CLR need to do verification process when it converts  Main function inside my application, it scans it and look for referenced assembly and if Native image is there then load it and start verification process and then compile the Main function to native CPU instruction and take the native code required for any function defined inside SomeType. please comment on this if i am correct.

Comment: Jeffrey Richter wrote a great piece in his book, he wrote in 2002 about Ngen'ing which is still relevant.

No Intellectual Property Protection. Many people believe that it might be possible to ship NGend files without shipping the files containing the original IL code thereby keeping their intellectual property a secret. Unfortunately, this is not possible. At runtime, the CLR requires access to the assemblys metadata and the NGend files do not contain the metadata.

Comment: @SumitRayakwar Your first comment is correct. Your second comment however, isn't. Native images generated with NGEN do contain metadata.